# HazelCast TransactionalMap, and concurrent thread access

Tags: java, multithreading, hazelcast, jta, distributed-transactions

Is it possible to access the `TransactionalMap` from `TransactionContext` with *concurrent multiple thread*..

Have enlisted the `xaResource` to existing transaction, Used `transactionalContext`, to get `TransactionalMap`, concurrent `*transMap,put(K,V)*`, takes me to an exception..
    `com.hazelcast.transaction.TransactionException:` *Transaction couldn't obtain lock for the key*. **HazelCast** version: ***3.6.3***.

Enlist:

```
HazelcastXAResource xaResource = hazelcastInstance.getXAResource();
Transaction transaction = userTransactionManager.getTransaction();
transaction.enlistResource(xaResource);
```

TransactionalMap:

```
TransactionalMap<String,Serializable>  transactionalMap=hcTransactionalContext.getMap("UUID");
    Map<K,V> map = transactionalMap.get("uuid");
             map.put(K,V);
```

Exception 1:

```
 com.hazelcast.transaction.TransactionException: Transaction couldn't obtain lock for the key: uuid
```

Exception 2:

```
There is no suitable serializer for class com.hazelcast.map.impl.tx.TransactionalMapProxy
```

Comment: Hello, can you share an executable reproducer? I couldn't reproduce it so far.

Comment: Repeating the same, step of transactional map bove mentioned, twice, (Put) parallel from two different threads, at the same time, will lock exactly at "transactionalMap.get("uuid");"

Answer (score 1):

Transactions in Hazelcast are designed to work by a single thread, hence it is not possible to do concurrent access  to the `TransactionalMap` in a transaction. 
If you explain your use case, maybe we can think of something better to achieve it?

Comment: Please find in detail in the link ... https://gist.github.com/VivekParanthaman/b745da11903a163d5657460abba101ae

Comment: Yes, thanks. Just to make sure this is not misunderstood; doing concurrent put operations for the same key (`uuid` in this case) in a `TransactionalMap` is not possible.

Comment: Even for different key is also not possible...!